# get html of a page in php

Tags: php, parsing, curl, file-get-contents

i have been trying to get the source of a page in php using `get_file_contents` and `curl` unfortunately both methods are not working for me. I am trying to use any method that will get the source of this page:

```
http://www6.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=524970&boxtag=7xpsk7&sec=form
```

This is a link for a chat box service I own and currently pay for. My goal is to create an announcement script and run a cron job that will send messages to my chat every hour. In order to do that I need to get the input variables for the form and one of them is `key` as seen here:

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="c126b4f134cb2c1184c1585fdfa4d1b0013a12f4">
```

Here is my problem. When using the methods I stated above it returns this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="">
```

Key having no value. So I need a method that will get me the key so that I can send message to the chat. Any help would be great appreciated :D

Update - Looking for closely at the source code i saw this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.cbox.ws/box/jsc.php?v=660"></script>
```

And there was mention of key so maybe its being generated by javascript? not sure exactly.

Comment: The question is, if you know php then why do you pay for this service?

Comment: @Neddy I have only been using php for about 6months and this service has a well developed shoutbox service and I have a 2 year subscription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (substr($site,0,7)!="http://")
    $site="http://".$site;

$site = str_replace(" ","%20",$site);

$file = fopen($site, "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

while(!feof($file))
{
  $temp = $temp.fgets($file);
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: I would love to vote this for you, but could you tell me how i would use this exactly?

Comment: @FAFAFOHI assign the site name to $site and after running this script you get the page's content in $temp

Comment: it returns the source but no key value :(

Comment: i think you can get the value of <input type="hidden" name="key" value=""> using regular expression or searching for **<input type="hidden" name="key" value="">** from the $temp

Comment: i used var_dump($temp) and it was not there

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the key is inserted by javascript? Or more likely it's a cookie issue so you might need to tell curl to send in the relevant cookie with the request.

Comment: This. Also the site could be sending the key only to requests with a web browser's useragent string. To avoid search engines reading it or something. If nothing else works try change it.

Comment: @Neddy I have tried various user agents and none of them work

Comment: What do i do if its being generated by javascript

Comment: @FAFAFOHI Ok then the problem is most likely cookies.

Comment: Wait no, its generated in the external javascript. I am not sure the exact process

Answer (score 0):

When I first load the URL, the value of that key is empty. When php load that page, it will load it as fresh as well. So, it's correct that it's empty.

You own that chatbox, do you have access to it? Why don't you modify that form to send you notification

Comment: I looked in the control panel but there is nothing there that allows me access to this. its a service called c box by the way.